# Compare-and-Swap on Django Model

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I would like to implement a compare-and-swap (CAS) operation on a Django model. I would like to set the state on a model only if the state in the DB matches what I think the state is. If not, I would like to raise an exception.

I am currently implementing this logic as:

```
if 1 != Model.objects.filter(id=obj.id, status=obj.status).update(status=status_to):
    raise ConcurrentWorkerException
obj.status = status_to
```

is this is best way to perform this operation or is there some ORM level feature that I should use?

Comment: Looks good to me. I can't think of a simpler way.